# Not able to remove the empty space while transpose in unix

Tags: unix

I'm exporting a file from a table to data.tmp, but it always created with empty line in the end.

file-darta:

```
5
6
<empty line>
```

I need to do transpose the data to make the output look like 
output:

```
5,6
```

I am using

```
cat data.tmp  |  tr ',' '\n' < data_1.tmp
```

But due to the empty space in the data.tmp file, i'm getting output as "5,6,"
How to remove the last comma.

Comment: It should be `cut -f:-1 -d','`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` to feed `tr`:

```
xargs -n 200 < file | tr ' ' ','
```

`xargs` merges all lines and then `tr` replaces the spaces with a comma.

#### Test

```
$  cat a
5
6

$ xargs -n 200 < a | tr ' ' ','
5,6
```

Comment: Nice! Note you can accept the answer if your issue is solved : )